# javascript library variables changing

Tags: javascript

I am working on a javascript library, here is the code:

```
    (function(){
        var elem,
            int,
            method,
            versrionInfo = {
                release : "0.2.1",
                date : "10/22/2013",
                releaseNotes : "Jist has been modified to handle lists of elements."
            },
            Jist = function(s){
                return new Jist.fn.init(s);
            };
        Jist.fn = Jist.prototype ={
            init : function(s){
                if(!s){
                    return this;
                }
                else{
                    this.length = 1;
                    if (typeof s === "object"){
                        this[0] = s;
                    }
                    else if(typeof s === "string"){
                        var obj;
                        obj = document.querySelectorAll(s);
                        this[0] = obj;
                        elem = this[0];
                    }
                    return this;
                }
            },
        }
        Jist.fn.init.prototype = Jist.fn;
        Jist.fn.init.prototype = {
            print : function(txt){
                for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
                    elem[i].innerHTML = txt;
                }
            },
            click : function(callback){
                for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
                    elem[i].addEventListener("click",callback,false);
                }
            },
            hide : function(){
                for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
                    elem[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
            },
            show : function(){
                for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
                    elem[i].style.display = ''; 
                }
            },
            fadeOut : function(ms) {
                var opacity = 1,
                    interval = 50,
                    gap = interval / ms;
                function func() { 
                    opacity -= gap;
                    for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
                        elem[i].style.opacity = opacity;
                    }
                    if(opacity <= 0) {
                        window.clearInterval(fading); 
                        for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
                            elem[i].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }
                }
                var fading = window.setInterval(func, interval);
            }
        };
        window.Jist = window.jist = window.Jis = window.jis = window.Jit = window.jit = window._ = Jist;
})()
```

And here is what I've got in my body section to test out my library:

```
<div id="fader"></div>
<input type="button" id="inpt" value="click"></input>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<script>
jist("#inpt").click(function(){
    //escape(txt)
    //btoa()
    //atob()
    jist("#fader").fadeOut(1000);
    jist(".test").print("hello world");
    window.setTimeout(function(){jist(".test").print("nata");},2000);

});

</script>
```

When I click the button, the divs with the class "test" fade out rather than my div fader.  This is because the library receives the signal to fade out the fader div but then receives the signal to edit the "test" divs and changes the variable `elem` to the test div.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this? Maybe returning a new `Jist()`?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you declared your elem variable, it is unique and accessible to all your instances of Jist. In other words, it is a global variable in the scope you created to define Jist. That way, each time you call Jist to create a new instance, you reset that variable for all instances.

In order for each instance of Jist to have its own, elem should be an instance variable. So, instead of having elem declared at the root of the namespace, you should declare it as an instance variable, for example like:

```
this.elem = obj
```

instead of

```
elem=obj
```

And afterward, each time you want to manipulate it, you need to access it with this.elem. Note that it also means that you will have to change the way you access it in some callbacks, for example the fade function. One way would be to bind the callback to your Jist instance like (ES5 only):

```
fadeOut : function(ms) {
    //snip
    var fadeCallback = function(){
        //manipulations on this.elem
    }.bind(this);
    //snip
}
```

or create a closure

```
fadeOut : function(ms) {
    //snip
    //note that this variable's scope is limited to this call to fadeOut
    var elem = this.elem;
    var fadeCallback = function(){
        //manipulations on elem
    };
    //snip
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this how jQuery does it? I am making a jQuery style library so I would like to know.